# XPath function position() &lt; x

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

**I have an xml document as shown below**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Results>
<InsertPtm>
<GdWfm022 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RowVersion>0</RowVersion>
  <ProjTeamNo>15</ProjTeamNo>
  <TeamMember>MFMAINT</TeamMember>
</GdWfm022>
<GdWfm022 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RowVersion>0</RowVersion>
  <ProjTeamNo>15</ProjTeamNo>
  <TeamMember>RC</TeamMember>
</GdWfm022>
```

and I want to select the Team member element from the GdWfm022 node set twice and assert test for MFMAINT,RC

Here is my XPath expression

```
<context select="/TEST/INSERTPTM/GDWFM022 [position() &lt;= 2] ">
<assert test="TEAMMEMBER = 'MFMAINT' "/>
<assert test="TEAMMEMBER = 'RC' "/>
```

I expect both the tests to pass but it fails, can someone help me to sort this issue.Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think a `select` should do in a `context` node? If this should be XSLT, you can  use  select in `xsl:apply-templates`, `xsl:for-each` etc..

Comment: Your select expresion begins with `/TEST` while your sample XML has `Results` as the root element, and your XPaths are all caps, while the element names use mixed case. I don't know what platform you're talking about, but generally, XPaths are case sensitive.

Comment: hello Hemanand, I don't think that JLRishe's solution will work right away because you also have a namespace issue. In <GdWfm022> there is a namespace declaration - you need to consider this in your XSLT. Compare: http://radio-weblogs.com/0118231/stories/2006/10/03/xslt10PatternMatchingTipsForSourceDocumentsWithNamespaces.html Show us your XSLT that you have so far! Best regards, PEter

Comment: @Peter, `<GdWfm022>` has namespace prefix declarations, but those prefixes are not used on `<GdWfm022>`. In fact `<GdWfm022>` has no namespace prefix. If there were a **default** namespace declaration (`xmlns="..."`), that would set a namespace for `<GdWfm022>`, but there isn't. So `<GdWfm022>` is in no namespace, and our XPath is looking for an element in no namespace, so everything is fine.

Comment: What assertion language are you using? Schematron?

Comment: @Lars: thank you for that explanation, I was wrong with my theory. Best regards, Peter

Answer (score 2):

Your select expression begins with `/TEST` while your sample XML has `Results` as the root element, and your XPaths are all caps, while the element names use mixed case. I don't know what platform you're talking about, but generally, XPaths are case sensitive.

How's this:

```
<context select="/Results/InsertPtm/GdWfm022[position() &lt;= 2] ">
<assert test="TeamMember = 'MFMAINT' "/>
<assert test="TeamMember = 'RC' "/>
```